# How can I extract text from single quotes, even if the text itself contains single quotes, using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract data from a .txt file and while my regex did work for the most part, it fails when it comes across single quotes within the text I'm trying to extract.

```py
{'pro_id':'1692423', 'pro_model':'SKUF42051', 'pro_category':'accessories', 'pro_name':'Gants tactiques Escalade en plein air Gants antidérapants résistants à l'usure Formation Gants de moto d'équitation', 'pro_current_price':'27.99', 'pro_raw_price':'27.99', 'pro_discount':'36', 'pro_likes_count':'11'}
```

This is what my text in the .txt file looks like.

I'm looping through and creating dicts from them. I do that by extracting the content from within the single quotes and appending the "key" and "value" pairs to a dict.

I've first extracted the content from within the curly brackets, then split that at ", " to get the "items" in a list, after which I looped through the list and used the regex in the command `key, value = re.findall(r"\'([^']+)\'", element)` to extract the "key" and "value".

I'm a regex as well as a programming novice, so I could use some expert help.

I did ask ChatGPT for a regex `'([^']+(?:\\'[^']+)*?)':'([^']+(?:\\'[^']+)*?)'` but that fails too.

I want to get a list that holds
`['pro_name', 'Gants tactiques Escalade en plein air Gants antidérapants résistants à l'usure Formation Gants de moto d'équitation']` from `re.findall`

but instead I get

`['Gants tactiques Escalade en plein air Gants antidérapants résistants à l', 'équitation']`.

Comment: Doing this with regular expressions is hard, maybe impossible in the fully general case. If this is Python syntax, use `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: aaaah, is that so? I was trying to avoid using the eval() but yeah, if it's not possible with regex then I'll give your solution a try. 

Thank you

Comment: `literal_eval()` is safe, not like `eval()`

Comment: But the string can not be parsed anyway. This single quote breaks everything.

Comment: look at the syntax highlighting and find that your input data is corrupt, you can't determine if a quote belongs to the string, the second quote terminates the string, use double quotes `"` or triple quotes `'''` or `"""` as string markers, or escape the quote inside the string`\'`, this can be parsed with a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is malformed. Strings containing literal single quotes should be enclosed in double quotes, else it can't be parsed correctly.

It is extremely difficult to use regex to sort this out, and also by using a `for` loop.

But I have discovered a way, I have found simple patterns. Since all strings are enclosed in single quotes, and the key value pairs are separated by commas followed by a space, and the keys are separated from values by single colons, it is easy to identify key value pairs by first split the string by `"', '"`, then split each substring by `"':'"`.

You can then convert it to `dict`, with cleanup if necessary.

Example:

```
import re

text = "{'pro_id':'1692423', 'pro_model':'SKUF42051', 'pro_category':'accessories', 'pro_name':'Gants tactiques Escalade en plein air Gants antidérapants résistants à l'usure Formation Gants de moto d'équitation', 'pro_current_price':'27.99', 'pro_raw_price':'27.99', 'pro_discount':'36', 'pro_likes_count':'11'}"
arr = [i.split("':'") for i in text.split("', '")]
def clean(s):
    return re.sub("^[{']+|[}']+$", '', s)

{clean(a): clean(b) for a, b in arr}
```

The result is:

```
{'pro_id': '1692423',
 'pro_model': 'SKUF42051',
 'pro_category': 'accessories',
 'pro_name': "Gants tactiques Escalade en plein air Gants antidérapants résistants à l'usure Formation Gants de moto d'équitation",
 'pro_current_price': '27.99',
 'pro_raw_price': '27.99',
 'pro_discount': '36',
 'pro_likes_count': '11'}
```

Wrap it in a function:

```
def dictify(text):
    arr = [i.split("':'") for i in text.split("', '")]
    return {clean(a): clean(b) for a, b in arr}
```

I assume you have many more strings like the above in your text file, since I don't know the exact format, I can only demonstrate how to convert the file to a `list` of `dict`s as if it is newline separated.

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
   text = f.read()
[dictify(row) for row in text.split('\n')]
```

You need to change the file path placeholder to the actual path. The above won't work if your file isn't newline separated.

And my method won't work if your string deviates from the format, for example if there are spaces after the key-value delimiting colons, or there aren't spaces after the commas that separate key-value pairs.

If that is the case I cannot help you, you need to figure out a different method, but my example does work on the example you have given.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the time you spent on this reply. Genuinely appreciate it. It works.

I had initially created a function similar to the one you posted above where I'd first step by step dissect the data.
First extract the content from the curly brackets with a regex, then split content at a comma and a space ", ", then split the data I get at ":", then use re.findall to extract the content from within the single quotes. But that would fail when the regex would encounter a wild single quote within the value of the 'pro_name'.

Comment: So I went back and tweaked it. Removed the regex to extract the key and value data from within the single quotes, and just sliced the data from the text using a[1:-1] which would give me the key and value data. BUT THEN, solving that revealed another issue where the splitting at ", ", would fail with the 'pro_name' value if it contained a comma and a space. This was the point at which I turned to StackOverflow for help.
Thank you again for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), I'm writing a regex answer. Regardless, your data is malformed and should not be parsed as such. Instead, correct it from the beginning.

```
'                 # Match a single quote, followed by
(?:               #           either
  '               #                  a single quote
  (?!\s*[:,}])    #                  that is not followed by one of ':,}' (not end of string)
|                 #           or
  .               #                  any character but a new line
)+?               # 1 or more
'(?=\s*[:,}])     # then a single quote followed by one of ':,}' (actual end).
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ToFLa3/1).

The above regex will not handle these correctly:

```
{'foo': 'a string with a comma', ' a colon ':' or a '}'', 'bar': 'baz'}
```

Comment: and then somebody creates an input that has a string that contains `bar 'foo': bar` and it will fail to be parsed, that is why they invented escaping

Comment: ...and that is why I said the data should be corrected instead.